# Django Rest Framework: How to randomize Queryset while keeping the pagination and search functionality?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Premise: Imagine I have 100 items in the database and each time the user opens the application I want to display 10 random items, and as the user scrolls down more items get added.

I started by creating a "ListAPIView" using a "PageNumberPagination" class:

```
class ItemListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemListSerializer
    pagination_class = ItemListPagination

class ItemListPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 20
```

This will give me always the same 10 items, so to randomize it I overwrote the "get_queryset" method and used a seed to randomize the queryset.

```
class ItemListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ItemListSerializer
    pagination_class = ItemListPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        objects = list(Item.objects.all())
        seed = self.request.GET.get('seed') # get the seed from the request query params
        random.seed(seed)  # set seed
        random.shuffle(objects)  # randomize objects
        random.seed()  # reset seed
        return objects
```

This works as expected but as soon as I introduce the SearchFilter backend, it errors out because is expecting a QuerySet and not a list.

```
class ItemListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ItemListSerializer
    pagination_class = ItemListPagination
    filter_backends = [SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['name']

    def get_queryset(self):
        objects = list(Item.objects.all()) # Get queryset and convert it to list
        seed = self.request.GET.get('seed') # get the seed from the request query params
        random.seed(seed)  # set seed
        random.shuffle(objects)  # randomize objects
        random.seed()  # reset seed
        return objects
```

This is the error I get:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

Is there a way of randomize the queryset using a specific seed without converting it to a list so the SearchFilter backend doesnt error out?

Or maybe randomize before it gets searched by the SearchFilter backend?

Hopefully someone can help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try using an if in the get_queryset()

```
def get_queryset(self):
    if searchfilter:
        return Item.objects.all()
    else:
        objects = list(Item.objects.all())
        ..
        return objects
```

Comment: If this works it will remove the random order when I use the search functionality. I want to always keep a random order on my results

Comment: get the search results then randomize and return then?